# How to to pass States between screens correctly

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and I've been playing around a bit, but I am struggling with this problem :

When there are multiple screens for an App, what is the best way to share the state between the different screens ?

I can make it work by passing the different Setter in the route.params props but I am nearly sure that this is not the best way of doing it ( + There is warning since I am passing a function in the navigation state )

From what I read, I could use React_Context / Redux / Recoil etc  ...
But I am not sure that I understand exactly how you are supposed to choose between each of those.
I can't manage to get a clear picture of this issue. If someone can enlighten me, thanks a lot

My code below :

## A.tsx

```
import React,{useState}  from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

function A(props): React.JSX.Element {

    const {navigation, route:{params}} = props;
    const {val_A, val_B, set_A, set_B} = params;

    const handle_A = () => {
        set_A(val_A+1);
        navigation.setParams({val_A:val_A+1,});
    }

    const handle_B = () => {
        set_B(val_B+1);
        navigation.setParams({val_B:val_B+1,});
    }

    return (

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>This is page A</Text>
                <Text>{val_A}</Text>
                <Text>{val_B}</Text>

                <Button onPress = {() => handle_A()} title = 'Add A'/>

                <Button onPress = {() => handle_B()} title = 'Add B'/>

                <Button onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('B')} title = 'Switch'/>
            </View>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor : '#fff',
    }
});

export default A;
```

## B.tsx

```
import React,{useState}  from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

function B(props): React.JSX.Element {

    const {navigation, route:{params}} = props;
    const {val_A, val_B, set_A, set_B} = params;

    const handle_A = () => {
        set_A(val_A+1);
        navigation.setParams({val_A:val_A+1,});
    }

    const handle_B = () => {
        set_B(val_B+1);
        navigation.setParams({val_B:val_B+1,});
    }


    return (

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>This is page B</Text>
                <Text>{val_A}</Text>
                <Text>{val_B}</Text>


                <Button onPress = {() => handle_A()} title = 'Add A'/>

                <Button onPress = {() => handle_B()} title = 'Add B'/>

                <Button onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('A')} title = 'Switch'/>
            </View>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor : '#fff',
    }
});

export default B;
```

## App.tsx

```
import React,{useState}  from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import A from './components/A';
import B from './components/B';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App(): React.JSX.Element {

    const [val_A,set_A] = useState(0)
    const [val_B,set_B] = useState(0)

    return (

        <NavigationContainer>

            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Stack.Screen name="A" component={A} initialParams = {{
                    val_A:val_A,
                    val_B:val_B,
                    set_A:set_A,
                    set_B:set_B,
                }} />
                <Stack.Screen name="B" component={B} initialParams = {{
                    val_A:val_A,
                    val_B:val_B,
                    set_A:set_A,
                    set_B:set_B,
              }} />
            </Stack.Navigator>

        </NavigationContainer>

      );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: To learn how to manage the state React docs is a good place to start: https://react.dev/learn/managing-state.

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass setter to another screen. In case you wanna share values between screens use a state engine like [redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux) or [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand)